# How can I determine the order in which text is read by a screen reader?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend, screen-readers

I have a created a checkbox component with vue. I am required to create an example checkbox with a two-line label. The first line could be a telephone number and the second line simply says "telephone number".

```
<checkbox>
  <div class="number">012345678</div>
  <div class="source">telephone number</div>
</checkbox>
```

Is it possible to let a screen reader read the second line (telephone number) first and then the first line (012345678) and if yes, how is it possible?

Comment: Whatever comes first will be read, much like you read a book in linear fashion. Just change the ordering of the `div`????

Comment: It will be read in source order. Although `tabindex` may interfere?

Comment: I am required to put "telephone number" at the bottom, that's why I asked if it is even possible to change the order read by screenreaders 
I will try the tabindex approach

Comment: That will only change the tabindex. Please make sure you know what changing it does. Otherwise you could make it _a lot worse_. https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2021-01-28-how-to-use-the-tabindex-attribute/

Comment: You can always turn on your operating system's reader or install one. That's not a bad idea for any front-end developer. A solution might be to position a visually hidden telephone link near the top of the document.

Comment: Your question asks two different things, by the way. Please revise it to ask just one (either about screen reader order or display order).

Answer (score 2):

It gets read in source order.  You can get around it a little bit by styling them to appear in a different order:

```css
.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <div class="number">012345678</div>
  <div class="source">telephone number</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various `aria-` attributes that can be used for such purposes.

There is for example the [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) attribute that you can use to tell which element should be the label for another element.

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <div class="number" aria-labelledby="phone-number-label">012345678</div>
  <div class="source" id="phone-number-label">telephone number</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **aria-flowto** attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-flowto

With that You can set custom reading order of html sections.

Update: I found out that aria-flowto is yet not supported by most of the screen readers. For now JAWS does support it, but NVDA does not. Take a look here: https://www.digitala11y.com/aria-flowto-properties/